# Disable Screensaver of XServer on Raspbian Jessie Lite

Tags: pi-2, startx, screen-saver

I setup a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie Lite in read only mode. To run a Qt application I installed the packages "xserver-xorg" and "xinit". I am starting the application automatically after boot from `/etc/rc.local` with following command: `sudo startx <application-path> &`

Now I want it to run for a long time without the screen going blank. I was able to turn off the screensaver for the console by changing `/etc/kbd/config` to this:

```
BLANK_TIME=0                        
POWERDOWN_TIME=0
```

and adding `consoleblank=0` at the end of the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

When I dont start the application and I stay in console this works and the screen stays turned on. But it seems that the XServer has its own Screensaver.

I installed `x11-xserver-utils` and tried adding this to `/home/pi/.xinitrc`:

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
```

But this file is never called (checked by adding the line `date >> /home/pi/checkFile`).
Typing theses commands or `xset q` myself gives the error `xset: unable to open display ""`

I also tried to add `setterm -blank 0` in `/etc/rc.local` which did not work.

Looking for solutions I found all kinds of hints which suggest changes in one or some of these files:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart        
/root/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc 
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
/etc/xorg.conf
```

But I have non of these on my pi, because (I assume) its just a Jessie Lite distribution and I installed the XServer myself (by installing packages `xserver-xorg` and `xinit`.

Any ideas what else I could try?